# Correct name for fixed/sticky/floating top menu nav bar thingy

Tags: menu, navigation, html, terminology, user-experience

When you scroll down a page and a menu bar appears at the top (could be elsewhere) and stays there (a la fixed `<div>`), what is the ***most correct*** term for this?  If you don't know what element I'm talking about see [Example1](http://jamesanderson613.com/) or [Example2](http://www.b14.dk/) or [Example3](http://www.oncarbure.com/en.html)

I've seen it called several different terms:

- sticky menu
- sticky toolbar
- floating menu
- floating navbar
- topmenu
- top menubar
- fixed navigation bar
- fixed menu
- awesome

but really, ***what's it called***??  And please, spare me the "personal preference" hogwash - I need some real meat.  Let's float some possibilities, navigate through our options, and fix an opinion that sticks.  ;-)

NOTE TO EDITORS: this is ON topic since I'm trying to code in semantic fashion -- what in the world do I use in my class and variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing with it.

#### Floating

If the bar is styled or otherwise programmed to remain in a specific position on a particular media even when you scroll away from it, then it is said to be floating.  Otherwise, it may be called "Static" if you want to be explicit.

#### Top, bottom, left, right

Independent of whether it floats, it may be any of these...Or even smack in the middle of your view... Although, that would be awkward...

#### Control or Navigation

Does the bar contain categorical lists of links divided into hierarchies?  If so, then this is a Navigation Bar.  Does it contain a search box or other options?  If so then it is a Control Bar, even if it also has navigational elements.

#### Bar or Menu

A bar would be what it is called if it stretches from the left of the largest or most prominent part of your viewable area to the right of that area, or top to bottom of that area, and takes up less than half of the area, be it a `<div>`, or whatever.  If it doesn't stretch for the entire length or at least a significant portion of it, you may want to use "Menu" instead of bar.

So, if you have a bar with only links or dropdowns with links to different parts of your site, positioned to float at the top, it would be a "Floating Top Navigation Bar".

If you had a left side bar with searchbox, radios, and links, that doesn't float when you scroll, it would be a "Static Left Control Bar" or just "Left Control Bar".  If it didn't stretch more than halfway down the side of the element, I would be more inclined to call it a "Left Control Menu"

Your user won't care what you call it, but anyone maintaining your code will at least know what you were trying to do.

Comment: If more people would be as deliberate with their words as you are outlining, the world would be a better place.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are all Fixed navigation bar, however their behaviors are a bit different, I guess these are what you are asking.

**Sticky**

It changes a bit when you scroll down page, and it turns to "float" on the top, with z-index attribution.

**Floating**

It always floats at the top with z-index attribution, which means the body content is under the bar even if is scroll on the very top.

**Fixed**

Always on the top and will not make change when scrolling down.